# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem, anche con cacert.pem

Tags: php, laravel, curl, mamp

I'm getting mad with this problem.
I have two sites on Laravel that are calling each other (login with OAUTH2, passport/socialite) on https. Both are installed locally on my dev server, on MAMP, certificates autosigned with MAMP.

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Everywhere I found this solution: put somewhere the file cacert.pem and write the path in php.ini. I did with
curl.cainfo="/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem"

Done, Apache relaunched, the setting appears correctly in phpinfo() on both sites.
Still, the errors persists.
Somebody can help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not written in English.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: Gosh, I didn't even notice it, sorry. Translated in English right away!

Answer (score 0):

After some research seems that the only solution is not to use https in developing/staging.